# WooCommerce Rest API Issue on local server

Tags: php, api, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a plugin to interact with a WooCommerce store and the problem is that the plugin and the store are on the same WordPress installation (same server and domain) and the WooCommerce Rest API didn't work. I have already asked this question:

[WooCommerce API Issue with Authentication Consumer Key is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602708/woocommerce-api-issue-with-authentication-consumer-key-is-missing)

My question: Is there a way to interact with WooCommerce directly without the Rest API, specially if my plugin and WooCommerce store are on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, in order to access the WooCommerce API directly without using the REST API I first found great code on this link:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/programming-question-memory-leak-when-accessing-products

And using this great link documentation

http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_file/includesapiv2class-wc-api-orders-php/

Then by navigating in WooCommerce Source code in the plugins folder under
plugins/woocommerce/includes/api

I succeeded to access WooCommerce, here is a simple example to get products of a category and using page number:

```
//you need to sign in with wordpress admin account to access WooCommerce data
function setupWooCommerce() {
    $wooCommercePath = realpath(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
    require_once $wooCommercePath;

    WC()->api->includes();
    WC()->api->register_resources(new WC_API_Server( '/' ));

    $credentials = [
        'user_login' => 'username',
        'user_password' => 'password'
    ];
    $user = wp_signon($credentials, false);
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
}

function getProducts($category, $pageNumber) {
    setupWooCommerce();
    $products = NULL;
    try {
        $api = WC()->api->WC_API_Products;
        $products = $api->get_products(null, null, array('category' => $category), $pageNumber);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log("Caught $e");
    }
    return $products;
}
```

Comment: Any possible updates for the new REST api of woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp rest api. below example show you last 12 orders:

```
        $request = new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wc/v3/orders/');
        $request->set_query_params(['per_page' => 12]);
        $response = rest_do_request($request);
        $server = rest_get_server();
        $data = $server->response_to_data($response, false);
        $json = wp_json_encode($data);
```

sources: https://wpscholar.com/blog/internal-wp-rest-api-calls/ , https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts